# Migrating to React - Using Composition instead of Inheritance in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

Hi I need some directions and advices. I have a task to migrate a codebase from javascipt to react.

Lemme explain this project to you

So this project has a quite simple codebase. I draw shapes and objects on a HTML canvas.

Those objects/shapes have some common properties, a few methods like `draw` 
for example: take this code from old codebase

```js
class Square extends Shape{
  constructor(height, width, fill,....){
    this.height=height
    this.width = width
    this.context = ...
    this.x = ...
    this.y = ....
    .
    .
  }
  draw(){
    ....uses canvas context and draws shape using x, y coordinates and stuff
  }
  resize(){
    this.height = ....
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now I have to migrate from this old code and start a fresh new React Project.

**Some Problems and Confusions**

- I read in docs that React doesnt expect us to use Inheritance. It uses Compositon. Can you explain me how can I convert these classes and use compositonn  with A little code example. Do I need to create a React Functional Component to replace this class?

  - In that functional component there I will use `useState` hook to create `height` , `width`, ....etc states and I will re-implement functions like `resize()` useing `setHeight`, `setWidth`, etc
- **Do I need to re-implement all data members like this:** - `this.height` and other data members of the `class` will be re-implemented using `useState`? I asked this because I think `resize()` method needs to written again that will use `setHeight` , `setWidth`  etc,.. as It will change `height` state and `width` state in order to resize shape.

*Note that* `fill`, `height` and `width` are not props passed to canvas. It is used by a function like `draw` and `resize` which actually RE-DRAWS in the canvas.

Also I am not moving away from canvas to HTML elements, I am trying to still do canvas, but based in React instead

Comment: I hate saying this, but if you're starting fresh with React, you shouldn't even really use classes. Switch to functional components. Once you have a few 'shapes', you might be able to spot if there's some common functionality between the shapes and create utility functions/custom hooks that are shared by all.

This will ultimately answer your question, but also means you're starting off with the correct modern way to React development. Classes are mostly 'old' now.

Comment: That said if you're doing canvas and you're drawing all these shapes on a canvas, you only probably need 1 react component: one that encapsulates the canvas. Each shape is not a react component I believe.

Comment: yes square is an object that I draw in canvas. Its not a React Component.

Also, I am using functional Components only. I am not using class components.

Comment: Alright. When you read stuff like 'don't use composition instead of inheritance', that's generally good advice but it doesn't apply to absolutely everything. A isolated example like 'shapes' sharing a common ancestor *does* make sense to me as an exception to the rule. So maybe don't worry too much about this?